# Classify change in a column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe, where it is already sorted by date and customer.
When the 'Appear' column is 1, this is when the Customer first appears in the dataframe.

I want to create a new column named 'ActOwner' where I will put 3 codes to inform which is the current Owner.

- When it is 0, it is considered as the original Owner, when Appear = 1.
- When there is a change of owner, the value of 'ActOwner' has to be 1
- When returning to the original Owner, the value of 'ActOwner' has what to be 2.

This is my example dataframe:

| date | Owner | Customer | Appear |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31/07/2022 | 810 | A | 1 |
| 31/08/2022 | 811 | A | 0 |
| 30/09/2022 | 811 | A | 0 |
| 31/10/2022 | 810 | A | 0 |
| 30/11/2022 | 812 | A | 0 |
| 29/12/2022 | 810 | A | 0 |
| 12/01/2023 | 810 | A | 0 |
| 31/03/2022 | 748 | B | 1 |
| 30/04/2022 | 748 | B | 0 |
| 31/05/2022 | 749 | B | 0 |
| 30/06/2022 | 749 | B | 0 |
| 31/07/2022 | 748 | B | 0 |
| 31/08/2022 | 810 | C | 1 |
| 30/09/2022 | 810 | C | 0 |
| 31/10/2022 | 810 | C | 0 |
| 30/11/2022 | 811 | C | 0 |
| 29/12/2022 | 812 | C | 0 |
| 12/01/2023 | 810 | C | 0 |

And this is my expected result:

| date | Owner | Customer | Appear | ActOwner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31/07/2022 | 810 | A | 1 | 0 |
| 31/08/2022 | 811 | A | 0 | 1 |
| 30/09/2022 | 811 | A | 0 |  |
| 31/10/2022 | 810 | A | 0 | 2 |
| 30/11/2022 | 812 | A | 0 | 1 |
| 29/12/2022 | 810 | A | 0 | 2 |
| 12/01/2023 | 810 | A | 0 |  |
| 31/03/2022 | 748 | B | 1 | 0 |
| 30/04/2022 | 748 | B | 0 |  |
| 31/05/2022 | 749 | B | 0 | 1 |
| 30/06/2022 | 749 | B | 0 |  |
| 31/07/2022 | 748 | B | 0 | 2 |
| 31/08/2022 | 810 | C | 1 | 0 |
| 30/09/2022 | 810 | C | 0 |  |
| 31/10/2022 | 810 | C | 0 |  |
| 30/11/2022 | 811 | C | 0 | 1 |
| 29/12/2022 | 812 | C | 0 | 1 |
| 12/01/2023 | 810 | C | 0 | 2 |

Could you guys help me how to build this new column 'ActOwner'? THank you

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
#test if Appear equal 1 
m1 = df['Appear'].eq(1)
#test if Owner per groups by Customer is same if Appear equal 1 
m2 = df['Owner'].eq(df['Customer'].map(df.loc[m1].set_index('Customer')['Owner']))
#test consecutive Owners
m3 = df['Owner'].ne(df['Owner'].shift())

#set final codes
df['ActOwner'] = np.select([~m3, m1, m2 & ~m1], [np.nan, 0, 2], default=1)
print (df)
          date  Owner Customer  Appear  ActOwner
0   31/07/2022    810        A       1       0.0
1   31/08/2022    811        A       0       1.0
2   30/09/2022    811        A       0       NaN
3   31/10/2022    810        A       0       2.0
4   30/11/2022    812        A       0       1.0
5   29/12/2022    810        A       0       2.0
6   12/01/2023    810        A       0       NaN
7   31/03/2022    748        B       1       0.0
8   30/04/2022    748        B       0       NaN
9   31/05/2022    749        B       0       1.0
10  30/06/2022    749        B       0       NaN
11  31/07/2022    748        B       0       2.0
12  31/08/2022    810        C       1       0.0
13  30/09/2022    810        C       0       NaN
14  31/10/2022    810        C       0       NaN
15  30/11/2022    811        C       0       1.0
16  29/12/2022    812        C       0       1.0
17  12/01/2023    810        C       0       2.0
```